# 'TypeError:Points is not a function' in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I'm getting this error while running the following code in Node
the first file is the dao file where it connect to a mongodb
the second is the server file
and the last one is index1 file

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
 mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');

 mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/base', function(err) {
 if (err) { 
     throw err; 
 }

 var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

 var IndexSchema = new Schema({
   indexp1: Number,
   date:Number,
   heure:String
 });

 var Index = mongoose.model('Index', IndexSchema);

 exports.Index= mongoose.model('Index', IndexSchema);

 var Points = function(date_debut,date_fin){
   Index.find({}, function(err, data){
      if(err) throw err;
      if(data.length > 1){
         res.render("index1", {datas: data})
      } 
      else{
         res.render("index1", {datas: "No names added yet!"})
      }
      return(datas);    
 });

};

module.exports =    Points;
```

---

```
 var dao = require('./daotest.js');
 dao.Points(15,15);
```

---

```
<% for (var i = 0; i < datas.length; i++) {%>
<p> <%= datas[i].indexp1 %> </p>
<% } %>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add your code directly to the question with file name instead of adding the image. see here for details https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Ok i added the code. thanks

Comment: Can you try fro this `module.exports.Points= Points `;

Comment: i try it and i have the same error !

Comment: @Sirine Abed Can you please post the full code of daotest.js??

Comment: @Subburaj yes i did it. Do you have any idea please?

Answer (score 1):

Change `Var` to `var`. Capitalization matters for keywords.

Answer (score 0):

May be you problem is in this line:

```
exports.Index= mongoose.model('Index', IndexSchema);
```

Because:

In any case if trying to assign a new object to exports ensure we do it this way.

```
exports = module.exports = {};
```

If we do it following way wrong way, module.exports will still be pointing to the object created as part of module instance.

```
exports = {};
```

As as result adding anything to the above exports object will have no effect to module.exports object and nothing will be exported or returned as part of require.

So try :

```
module.exports.Index= mongoose.model('Index', IndexSchema);
```

Hope helps you!!!

Comment: I did it ut i have always the same problem. it's really weird !